# Word order when using indirect object with a reflexive verb

Tags: pronoms, verbes, ordre-des-mots, pronoms-réfléchis

When using a reflexive verb and an indirect object pronoun in French, would the reflexive object or indirect object come first?

For  example,  I identify with them:

> Je me leur identifie

or:

> Je leur me identifie

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> je m'identifie à eux

is correct, as Fabrice stated. It needs a preposition, which none of your two examples gave.

*À* is used in this case NOT *avec*.

You shouldn't say:

> Je m'indentifie avec eux.

Comment: Yes I am aware there are accents needed, but not aware of how to use them on PC, I am used to Mac. Someone please fix it thank you.

Comment: The accent is fixed.

Comment: Based on the hits that I get with Google (4060 for "Je m'identifie **à** eux" & just 9 for “Je m'identifie **avec** eux"), you are clearly correct (to my satisfaction) that “avec” would be wrong in this case (+1 for that important observation). My “Le Robert-Micro,” however, gives an example of an actor identifying with his character using “avec” (Acteur qui s’identifie **avec** son personage); so (if you don’t mind taking the time to answer) are there any particular reasons to explain why “avec” would be wrong in this case that distinguish it from the example given by “Le Robert”? Thanks!

Comment: @PapaPoule You could make it a full-fledged question after checking there is no duplicate. It's interesting and there is an answer to that, which is close to your first observation and enables your Robert's stance on it at the same time. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to be late in responding. @PapaPoule  I agree that you should ask a new question, but I imagine it's for the same reason "L'homme AUX pieds nus". French ;'avec' is usually physical rather than in this case identify.

Answer (score 6):

French translation: *je m'identifie à eux*. 
I don't think there is any other possible.

Answer (score 3):

[It depends](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/double-pronoun-order/). It's not a matter of relative vs indirect, but the actual pronouns themselves.

Whether reflexive or indirect, *me, te, se, nous,* and *vous* always go first. *Lui* and *leur* always go last.

Edited: learn something new every day. The word order above is correct, but you can't say *je me leur ...*, it always changes to *je me ... à eux*.

Comment: whaaat ? not French !